# Double click on DataGridView cell to open a form

Tags: c#, datagridview, double-click

I have a form called **ListaDeAlunos** with a **DataGridView** on it.
When I double click on any cell, I want to open a form called **Alunos** for the selected row of the DataGridView on the form ListaDeAlunos, so I can edit the record.  I almost got it to work, but the form Alunos does not show the right record when it opens.

Here's what I did so far:

On the source form I created a class called **Variables**
and in that class I created a **public static string** called **RecordName**

```
class Variables
{
    public static string RecordName;
}
```

**On the source form I created a CellDoubleClick event:**

```
    private void tbl_alunosDataGridView_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {          
        Form Alunos = new Alunos();
        Alunos.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
        Alunos.Show();
        Variables.RecordName = this.tbl_alunosDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    }
```

**On the second form (the one that will open in the DoubleClick event), I have the following code on the Form_Load event:**

```
    private void Alunos_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
     this.tbl_alunosBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("Nome LIKE '{0}%'", Variables.RecordName);              
    }
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?  It's almost working!

Answer (score 1):

PROBLEM SOLVED !!!

All I had to do was to put the last line of code on top.  Simple.

```
private void tbl_alunosDataGridView_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{   Variables.RecordName = this.tbl_alunosDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();       
    Form Alunos = new Alunos();
    Alunos.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
    Alunos.Show();        
}
```